# Why does my function runs only once on onClick event in button?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, onclick

I've searched, but could't find a solution to my problem. I'm not an JS expert, just a novice, but I can't figure out why this works only once.
I have a SELECT droplist and I wanted to execute different instructions on different option selected.

I have 4 html blocks of text, only 1 is visible (display:block), the others are hidden (display:none). What I want to achieve here is to show only the selected block and hide the others, when I click the button.

Here's the code I've got:

```js
function filter() {
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt1') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt2') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt3') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt4') {
  document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="opt1">Display html block 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Display html block 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Display html block 3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Display html block 4</option>
</select>

<button onClick="filter()">Filter</button>
```

When I select one of options and click the button, it works as it supposed to. But when I select other option and click the button for the second time - it does nothing. The function executes only once.

Is there a simple way to fix it?

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt4'){...` is placed outside your `filter` function

Comment: Your code is throwing errors in console. There is an unmatched `}`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. One } too many. But in the original code that's not the problem and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the html block as well.

Comment: Without the typo is working for me, check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1fscba3/)

Comment: Guillermo, you're right, it works in your JSFiddle. But on the original page those HTML blocks are wordpress category listings, composed in WP Bakery as elements, and those elements have the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite related to the problem at hand, but if you change the values in the listbox to 1 to 4 you could simplify your filter function like

```
function filter()
{
    let value = document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value;

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        let id      = 'html_block_' + i;
        let display = i == value ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( id ).style.display = display;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as expected. Try this. I created blocks with the given Ids. We can always optimize this though.

```
function filter() {
if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt1'){
   document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';           
   document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
   }
else if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt2'){
   document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';           
   document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
   }
else if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt3'){
   document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';           
   document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
   }
 else {
   document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';           
   document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There's something else that's preventing your event to happen. If your filter function is in some custom js file, shift the function in your HTML file itself where you have your dropdown HTML code. Then try running it. Also put this console just after your filter function opening

```
console.log(document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value)
```

Also check this error in the console --> Cannot read property 'style' of null. Seems like your "html_block_index" element is not present in the DOM.

Comment: I've added the console.log and it's crazy. When I select opt1 it works and the console shows opt1, but then, when I select any other option and click the button, the console keeps showing opt1, no matter what I choose.

Comment: Are you sure the values in the select are actually "opt1" .. "opt4"? If they all were "opt1" (copy & paste maybe), that would show the behaviour described.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. All options have different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated snippet:
Please check the below, It works as expected

```js
function filter() {
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt1') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt2') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt3') {
    document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'none';
  }
if (document.getElementById('dynamic_select').value == 'opt4') {
  document.getElementById('html_block_4').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('html_block_1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('html_block_2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('html_block_3').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
  <option value="opt1">Display html block 1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Display html block 2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Display html block 3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Display html block 4</option>
</select>

<button onClick="filter()">Filter</button>
<div id="html_block_1">Block 1</div>
<div id="html_block_2">Block 2</div>
<div id="html_block_3">Block 3</div>
<div id="html_block_4">Block 4</div>
```